# Test tools for Database, Code (php), Security

Tags: php, database, security, testing, automation

What tools best fit to test automatically:

Code:

1. Copy/Paste code detector
2. Commented code checker

DB:

1. Encoding check
2. Field size check

Security:

1. XSS
2. SQL inject
3. Vulnerability scan

I am looking for tools that can automate process of testing, maintaining big projects.
So far I've looked at Selenium, PHPUnit.

Comment: What have you looked at so far?

Comment: updated question. Also i think that somewhere have been mentioned the tool that can make search in a project and provide places with commented code and copy paste code. But my search result failed when i started to look for it. My mistake that i didn't record the title of the tool. ;(

Comment: Took a look also on http://pmd.sourceforge.net/cpd.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this](http://phpqatools.org/) page.

Take a look at these:

- PHP Copy/Paste Detector
- PHP Dead Code Detector
- PHP Mess Detector
- PHP_CodeSniffer